# Update a referenced (proxy) document with Doctrine (CouchDB) does not work

Tags: proxy, doctrine, couchdb, bulk

I use Doctrine with CouchDB and it did work pretty well until now.

There is a document which references another document. Doctrine replaced the referenced document with one of its self-maintained proxy classes. Loading and accessing this proxy document works fine.

When I now do some changes which causes a DB update, Doctrine creates a bulk update query but does not include the _rev field. This causes CouchDB to reject the update.
Doctrine does not even load the _rev field when it loads the real data into the proxy class so there is no chance to put it into the update query.

Since this is a pretty common case (as I think) I am pretty sure I miss something.

How do I use these proxy classes? Is there a special way to update a document represented by a proxy class instance?

Thank you, danielkbx

Comment: I found a solution and reported a bug [here](https://github.com/doctrine/couchdb-odm/issues/70).

Comment: The Doctrine team did just accept my patch, it is now fixed and working in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Doctrine team did just accept my patch, it is now fixed and working in the repository.